# Regex to match 2-999 but not 1

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need a regex that matches all values from 2 and up, but not 1 (I won't encounter a zero in my "to-test" data).
I was trying [2-9]+ but then of course it skips everything from 10-19. And adding a 1 there didn't work :-)

Comment: It also skips 21, 31, 41 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
'[2-9]|[0-9]{2,3}'
```

Answer (score 6):

Parse it as number and then do your checks. Regexes are cool, but they are not golden hammer.

Comment: I totally agree, however, I can only use regexp in jmeter to filter out the correct part of the HTML code that is returned...

Comment: @Borniet I see now, you could indicate such details in question, so that people don't question the whole approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]|[2-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't the correct solution here, as parsing it as a number and then doing a numeric comparison would be far faster:

```
if number > 1 and number < 1000 then do something
```

However, in case you DO need a working regular expression, this should do the trick:

```
^[0-9]{2,3}$|^[2-9]{1}$
```